# Конвертация строки

Tags: javascript

Здравствуйте алгоритм простой показываю на примере
//  TestController => test_controller
Перед загловной буквой вставляем символ `'_'` и делаем заглавную - маленькой буквой. Моя проблема в тому что первый символ не должен принимать `'_'`

_test_controller - не правильно
test_controller - правильно

```js
function toUnderscore(string) {
    let splitStr=string.split('')
    const arr=splitStr.map(arr => arr===arr.toUpperCase() ? '_' + arr.toLowerCase() : arr)
    return arr.join('')
}
```

Comment: `console.log( "TestCont".replace(/(.)([A-Z])/g, "$1_$2").toLowerCase() );`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
function toUnderscore(string) {
    let splitStr=string.split('')
    const arr=splitStr.map((arr, i) => (i != 0 && arr===arr.toUpperCase() ? '_' : '') + arr.toLowerCase())
    return arr.join('')
}

console.log(toUnderscore('TestController'));
```

Comment: ну можнао так .